# Roots of Complex Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find all $x \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $(x - \sqrt{3} + 2i)^3 - 8i = 0$

I was able to find one value, $x = \sqrt{3} - 4i$.

I can also see that $x = -i$ also works although I am not able to devise a formal way for ending up with this value.

I am also unsure of how to find other values of $x$.

Comment: Hint: let $w=x-\sqrt{3}+2i\,$, then solve $w^3 = 8i$ for $w$.

Comment: Once you find one root, you can find the other two by quadratic formula.

Comment: You can even apply a sum/difference of cubes formula here. But @dxiv gives probably the most efficient route.

Comment: @u123435 there is no root at $x=-i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Divide your polynomial by $(x-(\sqrt{3} - 4i))$. You will get a quadratic polynomial. You found that $x = -i$ is also a root (great work!) so you should be to divide again by $(x+i)$.

Comment: There is no root at $x=-i$.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as
$$(x-\sqrt{3}+2i)^3=8i=(-2i)^3,$$
to find that
$$\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{3}+2i}{-2i}\right)^3=1.$$
So you're looking for roots of $w^3-1=(w-1)(w^2+w+1)$, where $w=\frac{x-\sqrt{3}+2i}{-2i}$.

Answer (score 1):

.Rewrite the equation as : $(x-\sqrt 3 + 2i)^3 = 8i$.

Express $8i$ in polar form, you can write it as $8 e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$.

Therefore, this question is basically asking you : what are the complex cube roots of $8i$? Thankfully, these can be answered via a use of De Moivre's theorem, which will tell you that the roots are precisely those of the form $\sqrt[3]{8} e^{\frac {i\pi}{6} + \frac{2in \pi}{3}}$ where $n=0,1,2$.

Now, this can be simplified:
$$
\sqrt[3]{8} e^{\frac {\pi i}{6} + \frac{2n \pi i}{3}} = 2 \operatorname{cis} \frac \pi {6}, 2 \operatorname{cis} \frac {5\pi} {6}, 2 \operatorname{cis} \frac {9\pi} {6}
$$

Expand using the fact that $\operatorname{cis} \theta = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$, and don't forget to subtract $2i - \sqrt 3$ from each of the cube roots. This gives an answer that involves only sine and cosine evaluation. Alternately, since you figured out a root, you could also have done polynomial division, but for that you would have to expand the cube root, which is laborious.

Comment: You forgot the "$i$" on the left of the bottom equation.  It should be $\sqrt[3]{8}e^{\left[\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2n\pi}{3}\right)i\right]}=$...

Comment: Yes, thanks. I should have edited that earlier!

Comment: You’re very welcome!

Comment: @RadialArmSaw I just felt nice after doing the edit, so seen your profile and up voted two of the answers you have written well. Thanks once again, and hope you contribute more on the site!